# Como cancelar a quebra de linha do <Text>?

Tags: react-native

Estou aninhando vários componentes `<Text>` em seguida, o problema é que no final de cada `<Text>` o React quebra uma linha.
Sei que se eu fizer dessa forma:

```
<Text>
  <Text>Oi</Text>
  <Text>Oi</Text>
  <Text>Oi</Text>
</Text>
```

Ele irá quebrar apenas no final, porém necessito realmente cancelar essa quebra de linha de alguma forma, pois durante meu texto haverá figuras no meio e outros componentes, e esta quebra de linha realmente está atrapalhando toda a formatação. Existe algum props ou algo que posso usar para cancelar a quebra de linha automática?

Comment: Tem como você dar mais informações da continuação do seu código? da parte que você diz ` e esta quebra de linha realmente está atrapalhando toda a formatação`, talvez seja algum outro problema e/ou pode ser resolvido de outra maneira.

Comment: Referente a cancelar a quebra de linha, dei uma pesquisada e não encontrei alguma maneira ou propriedade do text que faça isso.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando flexbox:

```xml
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <Text>abc</Text>
  <Text>123</Text>
</View>
```